# Odd UINavigationController and UIPopOverController behavior

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uipopover

I am presenting a popover with my viewcontroller:

```
     UIBarButtonItem *barButton = (UIBarButtonItem*)sender;
     SettingsViewController *settingsViewController = [[SettingsViewController alloc]      initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
     [self presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:barButton andController:settingsViewController andSize:CGSizeMake(RECT_POPOVER_SETTINGS.size.width, RECT_POPOVER_SETTINGS.size.height)];
```

and inside this view controller I have a button that pushes another view controller.

```
AnotherViewController *anotherViewController = [[AnotherViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:anotherViewController animated:YES];
```

Now in this view controller I have an action, and when it's done I do:

```
 [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Now the strange behavior is that when I pop the view controller, the

```
viewWillAppear
```

method gets called in SettingsViewController, then the breakpoints come back to pop method inside my anotherViewController.

This is a universal App so I am using this same setup on the iPhone, but without the initial UIPopOverController. This is functioning properly in the iPhone (with no popovers, pop method gets called first, then viewWillAppear), but on the iPad the viewWillAppear gets called first, then pop.

So my question is, can somebody explain why this is happening?

Thanks.